# Crash utility exit with error in Rhel6.6

Tags: redhat, linux-kernel, server-crashes, debug

Crash utility fails with below error.

crash /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.debug/vmlinux vmcore

crash 6.1.0-5.el6
Copyright (C) 2002-2012  Red Hat, Inc.
Copyright (C) 2004, 2005, 2006, 2010  IBM Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999-2006  Hewlett-Packard Co
Copyright (C) 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012  Fujitsu Limited
Copyright (C) 2006, 2007  VA Linux Systems Japan K.K.
Copyright (C) 2005, 2011  NEC Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999, 2002, 2007  Silicon Graphics, Inc.
Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002  Mission Critical Linux, Inc.
This program is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License,
and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under
certain conditions.  Enter "help copying" to see the conditions.
This program has absolutely no warranty.  Enter "help warranty" for details.

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"...

crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffffffff81587180  type: "cpu_possible_mask"

I installed "kernel-debug-debuginfo-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.rpm" and its dependend packages. kernel verion of vm is 2.6.32-504.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on 7.1.5-2.el7:

> crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffffffff818129b0  type: >"cpu_possible_mask"

and upgrading `crash` version to crash 7.2.3-8.el7 helped.